# Получите палиндром

Tags: python

Требуется найти самый длинный палиндром, получающийся из даной строки удалением любого(возможно, нулевого) количества символов

**Формат входных данных:**

во входных данный записана строка, состоящая из строчных английских букв. Длина строки не превышает 1000 символов

**Формат выходных данных:**

выведите искомый палиндром. если таких палиндромов несколько выведите любой

**Пример**

Ввод:anna Вывод:anna

Ввод:perevorot Вывод:ror

**Ограничение по времени:** 0.2 секунды

**Ограничение по памяти:** 64 мегабайта

Помогите пожалуйста с решением задачи. У меня есть код, но он верный только на 44 балла из 100. Ошибки: неправильный ответ и время выполнения слишком велико

```
a,c,ma=input(),'',0
for i in range(len(a)):
        for j in range(len(a)):
                c=''
                for k in range(i,j+1):
                        c+=a[k]
                if c==c[::-1]:
                        if len(c)>ma:
                                ma=len(c)
                                d=c
print(d)
```

Comment: https://neerc.ifmo.ru/wiki/index.php?title=%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0_%D0%BE_%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5

Comment: @КириллМалышев спасибо большое!